Create discord bot buttons programmatically
In my python discord bot I can define a discord.ui.View like this:
class ConfirmResetView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, cog):
        super().__init__(timeout=60)
        self.cog = cog  # Reference to the cog for resetting the event
        self.answer = None  # To store the user's decision

    @discord.ui.button(label="Yes", style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple)
    async def yes_button(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        self.clear_items()
        self.answer = 'Yes'
        await interaction.response.edit_message(delete_after=.1)
        self.stop()

    @discord.ui.button(label="No", style=discord.ButtonStyle.red)
    async def no_button(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        self.clear_items()
        self.answer = 'No'
        await interaction.response.edit_message(delete_after=.1)
        self.stop()

and use it inside commands like
view = ConfirmResetView(self)
message = await ctx.send("Are you sure?", view=view) 
           
# Wait for the user to respond (button click)
await view.wait()

print(view.answer)

I want to create a general-purpose View sub-class that I can use to generate questions with any number of buttons. I tried in a couple of ways like this:
import discord


class Question_dialog(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, cog, timeout=60, buttons=[('Yes', 'Yes', discord.ButtonStyle.blurple), ('No', 'No', discord.ButtonStyle.red)]):
        super().__init__(timeout=timeout)
        self.cog = cog  # Reference to the cog for resetting the event
        self.answer = None  # To store the user's decision
        
        for i, (label, answer, style) in enumerate(buttons):
            @discord.ui.button(label=label, style=style)
            async def button(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
                self.clear_items()
                self.answer = answer
                await interaction.response.edit_message(delete_after=.1)
                self.stop()
        
            setattr(self, f"button{i}", button)

and this
import discord

class QuestionDialog(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, cog, timeout=60, buttons=[('Yes', 'Yes', discord.ButtonStyle.blurple), ('No', 'No', discord.ButtonStyle.red)]):
        super().__init__(timeout=timeout)
        self.cog = cog  # Reference to the cog for resetting the event
        self.answer = None  # To store the user's decision

        # Loop over the buttons and create them dynamically
        for i, (label, answer, style) in enumerate(buttons):
            self.add_item(self.create_button(label, answer, style))

    def create_button(self, label, answer, style):
        # This helper function returns a button that has a separate scope
        async def button_callback(interaction: discord.Interaction):
            self.clear_items()
            self.answer = answer
            await interaction.response.edit_message(delete_after=.1)
            self.stop()

        # Create and return a discord.ui.Button with the proper callback
        return discord.ui.button(label=label, style=style, custom_id=f"button_{label}", row=0, disabled=False)(button_callback)

But when I call
view = Question_dialog(self) 

from within a function, this doesn't work and no button is showed. Where is the error?

The correct way to do this is by creating classes that inherit from discord.ui.Button:
from discord import ui, ButtonStyle, Interaction


class AnswerButton(ui.Button):
    def __init__(self, answer: str, style: ButtonStyle):
        super().__init__(label=answer, style=style)

    async def callback(self, interaction: Interaction):
        # you can access the view in which the button was added
        self.view.answer = self.label
        await interaction.response.edit_message(view=None)
        self.view.stop()


class QuestionDialog(ui.View):
    def __init__(self, cog, timeout=60, buttons=[('Yes', ButtonStyle.blurple), ('No', ButtonStyle.red)]):
        super().__init__(timeout=timeout)
        self.cog = cog  # Reference to the cog for resetting the event
        self.answer = None  # To store the user's decision
        for label, style in buttons:
            button = AnswerButton(label, style)
            self.add_item(button)  

and use it inside commands like
view = QuestionDialog(self)
message = await ctx.send("Are you sure?", view=view) 
           
# Wait for the user to respond (button click)
await view.wait()

print(view.answer)

